# Can I disable sorting in dgrid for performance gain?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, dojo, dgrid

With the particular dgrid I'm developing, I have no real need for client side sorting. I'm more after column, row and cell selection which I'm about to investigate via the Selection module, and the Resizing module which I've already implemented

My question is a) is there a way to disable sorting on the dgrid? how? and b) will this actually provide any performance benefit? If not then I may as well leave it in, but if it will be even faster without the feature, I'd like to remove it.

Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) Yes that is possible, you can set the `sortable` propery of each column to `false`.

b) Depends on how large the dataset is. It is best to profile this yourself. I don't think there is any visible performance gain if you turn off client side sorting if it is not used. But it will take up some memory of the browser when used on large datasets. But if you don't need it, remove it is always better.